# Put Image above Video and save video in android

Tags: java, android, video-processing, video-editing

I'm writing application which must put image above the video and save video.

In general application opens video file, after that user select image with transparent background and put that image above the video, after user press save button he get new video but already with image above the video.

Can you please provide me information or hints how to do that.

Comment: Do you have existing code already? We won't do the code for you, but we can help fix it. Basically, you put an ImageView (or a TextView, works too) with a transparent background over your VideoView.

Comment: @Wildcopper unfortunately I have no source code, as I never deal with video processing applications, the main thing that I must do is to put image above video and save it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as per your question, your looking for a video editor kind of solution to achieve the task..

I think this your scenario:

** You have a video in your application

** Open a bitmap resource (image file from some where)

** Overlay this bitmap at the bottom of the movie (video) on all frames in the background

** Save the video on external storage

For this ffmpeg does support overlaying functionality or [Android MediaCodec stuff](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest). **[FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)** has various filters one of them is overlay filter. What I understand is you want to overlay an image (i.e. png) on the video, ffmpeg surely is a useful framework to do this job. You can set the output format you can set the co-ordinates of the image which is to be overplayed.

E.g:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' output.avi
```

Above command adds overlays logo.png on the input.avi video file in bottom left corner.

More information about the filters is available at following website,

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1

Here is the GitHub links

[FFmpeg Android Java](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java)

[Android Java wrapper around ffmpeg command line binary](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)  or [this](http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)

If this is a solution to your problem you need the C code equivalent to the above command. You also need to see the performance of the ffmpeg because it a pure software framework.

Hope I have understood your question correctly and this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I think I describe problem in a wrong way, can you please check my updated question? I need to put image above video and save video.

Comment: i updated my answer you can check @ViTo Brothers

Comment: can I use this approach in Android application?

Comment: you can use this in Android.. I updated my answer with GitHub example source link.. Check it as well

Comment: @KingofMasses, can you please tell me what will be the command for image to be at center-top of the video?

Comment: @BSTKaal use relative layout and put your video view fill parent for relative layout and place imageview and set the property       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to the imageview and it vll be always top and put gravity center for it

Comment: Sory but i am asking about overlay position using FFMPEG, not in relative layout.

Comment: put image to video is a small function in my program, If I use FFMPEG it make my apk increate to >  10MB. Did you have solution for this problem ?

Comment: Will this work if I am drawing to canvas over video? Should I first convert the canvas drawing to jpeg?

Comment: Hi @KingofMasses, I would like to ask whether the overlay functionality is available for `MediaCodec`. In our app, we have already been using `MediaCodec` for processing video. And because of some reasons, I would like to put ffmpeg as the last option. What I'm looking into is the ability to overlay an animated image over a short video, something like this: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/v5h2tI_Bia0?t=2m33s)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean placing it just as a view overlay, it can be easily done in your layout XML.

You can place one view over another using `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <VideoView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="12dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="My customised view" />
</FrameLayout>
```